# 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013'

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, encode

I am using Wikipedia.py to fetch information from Wikipedia sections.
While doing so, I am having problem with encoding in the following Python code:

```
for section in data.sections:
        info = data.section(section).encode('utf-8')
        info = info.encode('string_escape')
        print info
```

data variable is the whole Wikipedia page.
Each time I run the script I receive the following error:

> 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013'

Comment: Obligatory reading https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

You must decode the `data.section(section)` first by the encoding of Wikipedia sections.

Suppose the encoding of Wikipedia sections is `gbk`, the code snippet is like this:

```
for section in data.sections:
    # Please check encoding in decode() first.
    info = data.section(section).decode('gbk').encode('utf-8')
    info = info.encode('string_escape')
    print info
```

Comment: This solution raises a different error: "'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0101'"

Comment: What is the encoding of Wikipedia sections ? You can check the encoding by wiki's web page source code.

Comment: It is `utf-8`, so you do not need to encode the section.

Comment: Without decoding, I can't escape the string. I receive the following error: "Must be string, not unicode"